# How to locate numeric data type information in the xml using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Below is the code, i just want to locate 8989 instead of ABCD in other set of transaction, usually we are expecting to get mix of items but we want to locate to the tree and node which contains only number data.

Tried searching numeric function in xpath but none seems to suite my case, usually there are only conversion functions available.
thing i tried :-

```
"number(.//dtv:IP[dtv:IPCode='LOGICLABEL']/dtv:IPValue)"
```

Here, Im getting everything as NaN(Not a numeric) even when this is number.

```
<dtv:IP>
 <dtv:IPCode><![CDATA[LOGICLABEL]]></dtv:IPCode>
 <dtv:IPType><![CDATA[STRING]]></dtv:IPType>
 <dtv:IPValue><![CDATA[8989]]></dtv:IPValue>
</dtv:IP>
```

VS

```
<dtv:IP>
 <dtv:IPCode><![CDATA[LOGICLABEL]]></dtv:IPCode>
 <dtv:IPType><![CDATA[STRING]]></dtv:IPType>
 <dtv:IPValue><![CDATA[ABCD]]></dtv:IPValue>
</dtv:IP>
```

In above code i just want to get   numeric value i.e: 8989 but my xpath should not locate on ABCD. 
Is it possible in Xpath?

Comment: Just to clarify, the only difference between those to locate and those to ignore is that in one case the CDATA are digits only and in the other case only uppercase letters between "A" and "Z"? Also please show what you have tried and explain how it did not work, that would help to avoid the impression that you are just listing requirements and waiting for somebody to program it for you. Maybe show the code you have which locates both cases and needs to be changed to only locate the one.

Comment: Hey Yunnosch, you are right thats the only difference we have no other tree particular for it. I have reedited the description on what i have tried.

Comment: I tried to fix your markdown, for readability, but do not dare to foul up your quoting. Please have a look at this and fix yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"number(.//dtv:IP[dtv:IPCode='LOGICLABEL']/dtv:IPValue)"
```

This is working good it is working when there are number, only thing is i have to replace the NaN which i described above with 0.

As near was able to get it till now using a translate function.

```
translate('NaN',number(/dtv:IP[dtv:IPCode='LOGICLABEL']/dtv:IPValue),'0')
```

My initial analysis with my attempt to solve was wrong, i apologizes for it.

Comment: No need to apologize. Making your own answer after finding your own error is actually appreciated here. However, you can improve by providing more details on how you solved it. Maybe state that the code you have shown (until now) in the answer is exactly the same as in the question. Which of course makes explaining the details of how you solved ELSEWHERE more important. How do you replace NaN with 0? (Just to clarify, you seem actually better at XPATH than I am and I am interested in the solution.)

Comment: Thanks Yunnosch, I think there must be improvements to be made but im posting this roughly.  translate('NaN',number(/dtv:IP[dtv:IPCode='LOGICLABEL']/dtv:IPValue),'0') using translate we can replace 'NaN' to 00 initially.

Comment: [edit] that into your answer itself (instead of hiding it in a comment) and I consider it worth an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
/dtv:IP/dtv:IPValue[string(number(.)) != "NaN"]
```

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only anwer with some explanation? Is this maybe what Jfrd means by "replace NaN"? It is more of "filtering the NaN away" isn't it?